# How to pass value from html to python and back using apache

Tags: python, html, apache

I am trying to implement a python game into a website. What I am trying to do is send a value that the user types in a text box (they need to click a button) from the HTML code to a python file on my PC and print the output under the button. When I run the HTML code in localhost it sends an alert (like "localhost says 1234"). I am trying to use apache as my webserver to do this and am going to run the website from that.

I am also able to print and send outputs to the localhost by running the python code through apache. What I am looking for is a way to send values back and forth between them. Here is my HTML code, I think I keep the user input as a variable named move.

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input  type="text" id="userInput" value="" placeholder="Enter your move" maxlength="4" />
    <input  type="submit" onclick="othername();" />
</form>
<Script>
    function othername() {
        var move = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
        alert(move);
    }
</Script>
```

Below is also my python code that I am trying to make work

```
#!C:\Users\ceqcx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
print("Content-Type: text/html/\n\n")

x="whatever value I get from the website"
print(x)
```

Thank you! I am pretty new to this so anything helps.

Comment: You can try a python framework like flask to implement a server that receive that data and replay to your game running on the browser. See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application

Comment: Be SUPER careful with allowing user input into a script.  Hackers love that!